# Shooting projectiles given an angle and power

Tags: actionscript-3, math, projection, game-physics

I'm doing a prototype game like **Worms** and I would like not only to shot, but also see the **whole projection curve** where my shot will travel before it hit the ground. The only information given by the player is an angle and a power. There is also some level elements like wind and gravity.

Can I have a code for the projection curve? its like a parabola I think. I research about parabola but I had some difficult to apply these math formulas into the programming code.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, please take some time to read through the [faq].

Comment: This seems more like a "do my work for me" type of question than a "what's wrong with my code" question. Read the [faq], you'll notice such questions are not really appreciated. nevertheless, I'm writing an answer below, it'll be ready soon

Comment: My apologies to everyone if I did some unappreciated question. I have no code about that because I just don't know how to do it. I have tried to apply the formula "y = a*x^2 + b*x + c" in a very noob way trying to plot 3 points of the parabola, but no sucess. If you insist i can put that in my post. But its just like nothing, i think. Sorry and thanks for feedback. Im trying my best.

Comment: It seems the simplest thing to be would be to keep an x increment of 5px and then find the y coordinate for every x coordinate and then join them with lines. I trust this should be simple enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The math (and physics) part**

So this seems like 10th grade physics to me.

The path trced by a projectile is (as you said) a parbola describable by the equation

[image: Projectile differential equation]

Now, if you solve this equation, you get the following parameters:

Range:  [image: Range of projectile]

Height: [image: Height of projectile]

(vi = initial velocity, theta i = initial angle of shooting wrt horizontal)

And, the equation in `(x, y)` for the parabolic path will be

[image: Prabola path equation]

(v0 = initial velocity, theta = firing angle)

**The programming part**

assuming the following constants:

```
const g:Number = 9.81; //9.81 m/s, the grav const
```

The sin function is available as `Math.sin`

The power function is available as `Math.pow`. This means, sine squared will be

```
Math.pow(Math.sin(theta), 2)
```

You *could* write the range function as

```
function projectileRange(vel:Number, angle:Number):Number {
    var vsquare:Number = vel * vel;
    var rv:Number = vsquare * Math.sin(2 * angle) / g;
    return rv;
}
```

and the height function as

```
function projectileHeight(vel:Number, angle:Number):Number {
    var vsquare:Number = vel * vel;
    var rv:Number = vsquare * Math.pow(Math.sin(angle), 2) / (2 * g);
    return rv;
}
```

and the yPosition function as

```
function yPosition(xPos:Number, vel:Number, angle:Number):Number {
    return xPos * Math.tan(angle) - (g * xPos * xPos / (2 * vel * vel * Math.cos(angle) * Math.cos(angle)));
}
```

Note that the angles are in RADIANS

```
function toRadians(degrees:Number):void {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

For more information on projectile motion, [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=projectile%20motion) it.